# Increase images in nearby mode - jssor slider

Tags: jquery, jssor

I'm trying to have the jssor slider in a site, where I'm trying to increase the number of nearby images to 4 and add a class into the middle image so that I can highlight it. 
Went through the code for default 2 nearby mode, and tried to play with the parameters but with no luck.

If there is something like that possible, I'd like to know where to look into the code to get that done.